# Freeswitch Issues incoming call Abandoned

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I have a server with FS, my problem is making a call to FreeSWITCH from my personal phone. The incoming call is detailed by FS, but it doesn’t process throw DialPlan. Mi server IP is `166.227.33.23` and the incoming call is to throw `65.34.236.149` as you can see in next sip trace. 
Thanks for helping me

SIP TRACE: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQBV5eWmD3TVMt_kTT-faLxqTxS1OGnV/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in logs you're getting 
Rejected by acl "domains". Falling back to Digest auth.

So you have two options :

1. Add 65.34.236.149:5060 to [ACL](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/ACL) if this is your FIXED IP.
2. OR Configure your phone as extension for freeswitch to authenticate with username/password if you have different users(phones) in your network

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your answer, I tried to add the ip in all but I always get this error
[ERR] switch_utils.c:518 Error Adding 65.34.236.149:5060 (allow) [] to list domains
I also tried without :5060
But I solve the problem adding a gateway with this IP.
Thanks anyways